# The offending line appears to be in ansible

Tags: ansible

```
- name: test-loop
  hosts: machine1
  become: True
  tasks:
       - name: "Installing Packages"
         apt:
            name: "{{item}}"
            state: present 
         with_items:
                   - tree
                   - apache2
```

What's wrong with this yaml file, I am getting the error

The offending line appears to be:
tasks:
- name: "Installing"
^ here

Comment: As you pasted it, there are no syntax errors in your playbook. Did you paste all of it ?

Comment: Not related to your current problem: don't loop on the `apt` module. Send the list of packages directly in the `name` option`. See th [notes in the module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#notes)

Answer (score -2):

Ok I got the problem

```
- name: test-loop
  hosts: machine1
  become: True
  tasks:
       - name: "Installing Packages"
         apt:
            name: "{{item}}"
            state: present 
            with_items:
                      - tree
                      - apache2
```

Now working fine.

Comment: `apt` has no `with_items` option. This is a task level keyword. Your example is not a valid ansible task. Even if `apt` decides to ignore this non existing option (which I seriously doubt), there will be no loop, hence no `item` variable and you will get an undefined variable error.